# Django recursive imports

Tags: django, recursion, import, models

I have two apps: pt and tasks.

pt.models has a Member model.
tasks.models has a Filters model.

Member model has a foreign key to Filters model (one for a member).
Filters has M2M field to Member as it holds some kind of filtering settings.

So, I must recursively import both models to get everything synced what is impossible in Python.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Again, circular imports are not an error in Python, only using names that don't yet exist when doing so.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself...

Comment: I tried to write model names in quotes, but then it says that it cannot find models related. If I still use imports, then I get import error as imports are recursive.